# Entity Framework returning no data when joining on a nullable field even though the underlying query does return data

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting a baffling result from EntityFramework. I have the following query:

```
Dim dbTeamAndContact1 =
(
From t In db.Teams.Where(Function(x) x.TeamId = 123456)
Join c In db.Contacts
On t.ContactId Equals c.ContactId
Select New With {.Team = t, .Contact = c}
).
FirstOrDefault
```

This is an extremely simple join, with the possible wrinkle that Team.ContactId is nullable, but is *not in fact null* for the specified team id.

When I run this, I get Nothing/null back from Entity Framework. But when I obtain the underlying SQL statement that EF is using and run that directly against the database, it's a straightforward INNER JOIN statement that *does* return the expected team and contact. But somehow, EF is getting confused when returning this data to client code.

I cannot see anything wrong with the code. What is going on here?

Comment: Double-check that the query is executing against the Database you expect it to be. The connection string at runtime may be pointing at a different database.  Run a profiler against the database to capture the exact SQL being run then run it against that same database. If it returns data for both the team and contact but EF isn't populating one/both then something weird is happening.   Have you considered leveraging navigation properties so Team can have a reference to it's Contact? (Generally a lot easier to work with than explicit joins)

Comment: Yes, that turned out to be the problem. An unrelated bit of middleware had me pointing at the wrong database, which had similar enough data that it wasn't obvious, but different enough to cause this issue.  I should use navigation properties, but I just haven't gotten around to learning how they work.